# Initialising Matrix in Eigen

Tags: c++, eigen

Im trying to initialise a 6x4 matrix using Eigen library as follows;

```
    MatrixXf DH(6,4);
```

in my class definition. But this results in error 
        `Expected parameter declarator`

According to Eigen [tutorial](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/group__TutorialAdvancedInitialization.html) what I am doing is correct. Any thoughts?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you have this:

```
class Test {
    MatrixXf DH(6, 4);
public:
    Test() {
    }
};
```

The `(6, 4)` means you are calling the constructor. But you can't call non-static functions in a parameter declaration. This is what parameter lists are for:

```
class Test {
    MatrixXf DH;
public:
    Test() : DH(6, 4) {
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Most probably the declaraction is being confused for a function.

Try initializing the matrix inside the class's constructor initialization list, since initializing it inside the constructor is not possible unless it is a pointer and you allocate memory for DH inside.

```
public:
    YourClass() : DH(6, 4)
    {

    }
```